# How to intern objects with weakref/gc support?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, weak-references

I'm trying to implement interning of non-string objects in python. For strings we have the `sys.intern` function. However it doesn't support other immutable objects. To put it out of the way, I'm aware of the problems that may arise when the interned objects are modified.

A commonly cited way of interning for non-strings is:

```
S = {}
x = S.setdefault(x, x)
```

However such a `dict` holds strong references to the interned objects, and therefore will grow indefinitely, which is a problem in my application.

I figured out that there's a `WeakSet` type that would auto-collect unreferenced elements. However there doesn't seem to be a fast way to get the held object in the set:

```
S = WeakSet()
S.add(x)    # returns nothing

# a very slow way to work around it:
for y in S:
    if y == x:
        x = y
```

There are also `WeakKeyDictionary` and `WeakValueDictionary`, but there doesn't seem to be a `WeakKeyValueDictionary`.

So how can this be achieved in python?

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate a `WeakKeyValueDictionary` by creating a weak reference to the object as a key and then storing the object as a default value of a `WeakValueDictionary`:

```
from weakref import ref, WeakValueDictionary

def intern(obj, weak_refs=WeakValueDictionary()):
    return weak_refs.setdefault(ref(obj), obj)
```

so that:

```
import gc

a = frozenset(['x'*10000])
b = frozenset(['x'*10000])
assert a is not b
a = intern(a)
b = intern(b)
assert a is b
print(len(intern.__defaults__[0]))
del a
del b
gc.collect()
print(len(intern.__defaults__[0]))
```

passes both assertions and outputs:

```
1
0
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/UsableSpecificProcessors

Comment: Hmm... yeah, in this case, when the keys and values of a hypothetical WeakKeyValueDictionary would be the same object, just creating weakrefs on one side yourself should work. It doesn't when the keys and values would be different objects - you run into problems with cleanup not happening properly, or cleanup not interacting properly with the internal iteration guard.

Comment: It'd be simpler to just use an ordinary function instead of a class with a `__new__` override. It's not like you'd ever want an actual instance of `Intern`.

Comment: I made it a class so that I could output the content of the weak container more easily, but yeah, if I make it a function and the weak container as the default value of a parameter, I can still use the `__defaults__` attribute to access the weak container, just in a slightly uglier way, but it doesn't matter because the ugliness is only in the debugging code only, while the actual code is cleaner when written as a function indeed.

Comment: Keys and values are always sync'd to the same objects for this application, so there won't be any cleanup issues.

Comment: Is there any reason to have WeakValueDictionary with ref() keys, versus WeakKeyDictionary with ref() values?

Comment: @YakovGalka The only reason is that in the end we want to retrieve the object rather a reference to the object after all, so if we used a `WeakKeyDictionary` with `ref`'d values, we would have to make an extra call to retrieve the object from a value reference, incurring slightly more overhead. Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/SoggyDependentHardware